# Pass multiple parameters in Spring batch

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-batch

How can I pass multiple parameters in Spring Batch ?

Example I have a file name ABCYYMMDD00.txt. The YYMMDD represents the current date and pass from Main Class, ABC is fixed and 00 also pass from Main Class.

```
 <bean id="detailReader" class="com.rh.app.ReadFile" scope="step">
        <constructor-arg name="fileName" value="/home/xxx/IFD+#{jobParameters['stmtDate']}+#{jobParameters['No']}.txt"/>
    </bean>
```

But this look wrong to me.

Comment: And why would that be wrong? You want 2 parameters so you have to retrieve them both. You might be able to put it in a single SPeL (not sure though).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We use the following to pass the multiple parameters to a job

```
private JobParameters buildJobParameters(String date,String wfId){
   return new JobParametersBuilder().addString("wfId", workflowId).
                        addDate("rundate", runDate);
}

JobParameters jobParameters = buildJobParameters(date,wfId);
JobExecution execution = jobLauncher.run(job,jobParameters);
```

So, can be easily achieved in your case.

```
private JobParameters buildJobParameters(String stmtDate,String no){
       return new JobParametersBuilder().addString("stmtDate", stmtdate).
                            addDate("No", no);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

`JobParameters` constructor takes map of JobParameter as input. You can pass any number of Parameter.

Below is sample code

```
 Map<String, JobParameter> map = new HashMap<String, JobParameter>();
           JobParameter myParameter = new JobParameter(parameter1);
           map.put("key1", myParameter);
           JobParameter myParameter = new JobParameter(parameter2);
           map.put("key2", myParameter2);
           JobParameter myParameter = new JobParameter(parameter3);
           map.put("key3", myParameter3);
           JobParameters jobParameters = new JobParameters(map);
```